# Content Query Webpart. File icons not lined up. Corrupted web part?

Tags: content-query-web-part

I am trying to build on a new (SharePoint 2016) site.
I've added the content query web part but it is not looking right. 
Doing a quick test of some files, it displays like this:

[image]

Something didn't look right, so I went back to another site I used to use. This site is on a different site collection, still 2016.

Doing a quick test on this other site, this is how it displays files using the CQWP:

[image]

I have gone over every setting I can find on both site collections and they match. Yet this web part is not showing right. The icons are not lined up and those bullets will not go. 
I've even made it so it shows a custom file type image. That looks like this:

[image]

On the other site, they show up like this:

[image]

Comment: If you know how to use the built-in browser Dev tools to examine what css is being applied, just looking at the layout difference, I would say each site's css is a little different, with one declaring that class with a block style and the other with an inline or float style.

Comment: Having a look through the code it seems the site which is working is loading a separate style sheet. No idea why this one does not. If I change the grouping style nothing changes.

Comment: Different site templates may implement additional styles.  Also, I don't know the history of your environment, but if power users or developers built specific customizations in some sites, they may have implemented custom style sheets as part of that.